# How is PHP a Scripting Language when it's written in C?

Tags: php, c

This question has been bugging me for a while. It may sound silly though!

I understand from the [PHP Source Code](https://github.com/php/php-src) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393547/what-language-are-inbuilt-php-functions-written-in) that PHP core functionalities are written in C. Now, given that C is a compiled language, I was wondering how is PHP a scripting language? Also, PHP is object oriented, while C is not!

I wanted to know how it works internally, or some high level details. So, how is this abstracted?

Comment: I dont get what you mean. The php interpreter is just written in c. Where is the problem?

Comment: C's compiler is written in C too, what's your point?

Comment: C++, Java, Python, C# and many other object oriented programming languages too are written in C.

Comment: I thought PHP compiles to C. Doesn't it?

Comment: @vnay92 no it doesn't. Where did you get that information from ?

Comment: PHP doesn't compile it gets interpreted. Facebook developed a compiler for PHP called HHVM, this compiles PHP code to C++

Comment: Strictly speaking, PHP isn't an interpreted language, but a JIT (just in time) compiled language.... meaning that it's compiled at run-time..... and it's compiled (like Java and many other cross-platform languages) not directly to machine code, to an intermediate bytecode that the run-time engine can then execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start at the beginning you need to understand that features like object orientation don't make a language more powerful. There is nothing that can be done with an object oriented language that can't be done in Assembler. Object orientation is just a different way of writing things.

So for example, if you have a class like this (using Java here, but it's the same for any other object orientated language):

```
class Foo {
    int x,y;
    int getSum(int z) {
        return x+y+z;
    }
}
```

That is equivalent to

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
}
int getSum(Foo foo, int z) {
    return foo.x+foo.y+z;
}
```

So here you have some code that does exactly the same as the code above, but is not object oriented. So any compiler or interpreter that compiles or interprets object oriented code translates that code into something the machine understands by creating code that does the same as the object oriented code, but without the object orientation. Furthermore it actually translates it into machine code that does the same thing that the original code did.

@the second point (why is PHP interpreted while c is not):
Think of the PHP interpreter as a program, written in c, that just walks over your code and executes whatever the code does. What comes next is greatly simplified. Take that example (it's once again in Java, but again, it's about the same in any language):

```
String phpCode="print('Hello World');exit();";
String[] tokens = phpCode.split(";").strip();
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (token.startsWith("print")) {
        String param = phpCode.replace("print(","").replace(")","");
        System.out.println(param);
    } else if (token.equals("exit()")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

What this does is it interprets the content of `phpCode`. It currently understands the keywords `print` and `exit`. An actually usable interpreter is much more complicated, but that's the basic concept. It runs over the code, splits it into pieces that it can understand and then executes code that does what the interpreted code should do.